# MAX DATE With NULL VALUE

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Trying to get the max date from my table, i can't retrieve the value when the date is null. 
Sample :

the following table :

```
+----+--------+------+------------------------+
| id | parent |    Date                       |
+----+--------+------+------------------------+
|  1 | Alex   |   2018-10-01 00:00:00.0000000 |
|  1 | TIM    |   2012-11-07 00:00:00.0000000 |
|  3 | Cath   |    NULL                       |
+----+--------+------+------------------------+
```

To get the max date im using the following:

```
select id, Parent, Date From Table T1
Where Date = (select Max(Date) from Table T2 where T1.id= T2.id )
```

Wich works fine for the id = 1
But for the id = 3 it's not working

The result is :

```
1 | Alex   |   2018-10-01 00:00:00.0000000
```

Any ideas Why?

Comment: What is your expected result? IMHO it is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aggregated functions does not consider rows with NULL values.

You could use a WINDOW FUNCTION to enumerate rows and then get first row only:

```
with ct as
(
    select id, Parent, Date,
           row_number() over (partition by id order by id, date desc) rn
    from   tbl
)
select id, Parent, Date
from   ct
where  rn = 1
order by id;

id | Parent | Date               
-: | :----- | :------------------
 1 | Alex   | 01/10/2018 00:00:00
 3 | Cath   | null
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=244f7d248ae0e3a32639905aefd7617f)*

Comment: If the OP wants the max date shouldn't the order by in the window just be `date desc`?

Comment: @AaronBertrand you're right, edited.

Comment: Sweet ! i just changed as @AaronBertrand suggested the order by THANKS a lot!

Answer (score -2):

As McNets states, this is normal SQL behaviour. You have to watch out using NULL's in comparisations since NULL is actually everything.

You might be able to solve this to set a "dummy" value to the NULL value.
This way you can select the NULL value as the highest date.

```
select CASE WHEN MAX(COALESCE(Date, 1000000)) = 1000000 THEN NULL ELSE MAX(Date) END as Date
from Table T2 where T1.id= T2.id
```

Comment: Have a look at fiddle I've supplied in my answer, if there is more than one row with null values for the same ID this solution doesn't works.

Comment: Hi McNets, I have to agree. If the Id has multiple Null-values it will return both rows for this Id.